# Cufon canvas partially covers a clickable area

Tags: css, xhtml, cufon

I'm experiencing a problem with Cufon text-replacement library.

Take a look at:

http://www.dgform.com/new/

Next to the "Twitter" header there's a bird icon, which should be clickable, unfortunately the Cufon canvas - which strangely takes a lot of blank space after the last letter - lays partially on the image, so that it becomes clickable only a tiny portion on the right (a sniper's job to find it ;) ).

Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this on the a tag that contains the bird icon:

```
h1.twitter a {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

This will put the a tag above the cufon text.